# How to create a union from the values of an Object with JSDOC

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a String enum defined as follows:

```
//Note how the keys and the values are different. 
const myStringEnum = {
value: "value1",
anotherValue: "value2",
yetAnotherValue: "value3",
}
```

and I have a function that takes 2 parameters. The first parameter needs to be one of the values  from the `myStringEnum` enum.

Example:

```
function foo(param1, param2){

  switch(param1){
   case "value1" : 
      //logic
    break;
   //etc
  }
}
```

I want to document through JSDoc that param1 will be a union like this: `("value1"|"value2"|"value3")`

I know I can do that directly in JSDOC, however I am wondering if I can do it programatically so if I modify the enum, JSDOC will automatically populate the union.

I know that if the values and the keys inside the enum were the same, for example:

```
const anotherEnum ={ 
value1: "value1",
value2: "value2",
}
```

Then I could simply use the `keyof` operator as such:

```
/**
*
* @param {keyof anotherEnum} param1
*/
```

However, unfortunately, with the code I am working on, the key/value pairs must be different.

Is there anything that I can do through JSDOC which will allow me to get `("value1"|"value2"|"value3")` from `myStringEnum`. Like maybe:

```
/**
*
* @param {myStringEnum[keyof myStringEnum} param1
*/
```

P.S I have tried that and it infers the type `string` but not the actual value.

Comment: When you hover over `anotherEnum`, what is it't type?

Comment: @blaumeise20 if i hover over it in the JSDOC documentation it says any, which is weird because it still correctly infers that param1 will be one of the keys of anotherEnum